# The sound of coffee

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the sound pitch increase on every consecutive tick at the bottom of a filled cup of coffee?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23038/why-does-the-sound-pitch-increase-on-every-consecutive-tick-at-the-bottom-of-a-f)

A colleague suggested this experiment this morning :

- Get a cup of coffee
- Spin the coffee in the cup using a spoon
- Tap the bottom of the cup with the spoon

*Observations* : As the coffee slows down, the sound produced by the tapping gets higher in frequency.

I'm very curious about this, does anyone have an explanation ?

Comment: See this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23038/why-does-the-sound-pitch-increase-on-every-consecutive-tick-at-the-bottom-of-a-f

Comment: The situation described is not identical to the the one in the proposed duplicate, but I think that the explanation *is*. I'm going to close this as a duplicate, but would be willing to re-open if anyone expresses a desire to write an answer about the quantitative differences. Just flag.