# Why does Stirred (rotating) coffee alters cup’s resonance frequency?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, acoustics

I place a spoon in my cup of (dolce gusto lungo) coffee and tap the bottom of the cup with my spoon.  It emits a certain (fixed) frequency.  However, if I stir the coffee (but not so fast that the surface of the coffee has any appreciable dip in the centre) and repeat the tapping in the centre with the spoon the frequency sounds lower initially but rises as the coffee stops rotating.  Curiously it appears to continue rising for a brief period after the coffee appears to have stopped rotating in the cup.
What’s happening?
 Is it related to the fact that if I stir the coffee fast enough then all the “froth” on the top of the coffee disappears (subsumed into the coffee?), but reappears as the rotation slows down.
Other than stirring the coffee nothing is being added.

Comment: It also works for hot chocolate.

Comment: If somebody does not know the effect please see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Hr_zFdNW5Q).

Comment: What frequency does it emit then?

Comment: Thanks Fabian, have seen the link and that explanation sounds correct.  Pieter - cannot see the relevance of the frequency (1451Hz).  The bubbles/gas in the solution seems plausible as the effect does not occur with just plain water.  Ta.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_chocolate_effect. See also [Why does the sound pitch increase on every consecutive tick at the bottom of a filled cup of coffee?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23038)